# Dropdown won't hide after clicking (plain HTML, CSS and JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, dropdown

I have a responsive navbar with a dropdown. Works well in PCs (the dropdown only pops up on hover of the cursor) but when I try it with smartphones (the navbar is adjusted) if I activate the dropdown any link in it will reload the page properly but the dropdown is still there. I want to solve the issue without jQuery if possible.

I'm working with django, that's why I use {{ }}

```
<!-- navbar.html -->

{% load static %}

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/navbar.css' %}">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a class="active" href="{% url 'inicio' %}">Inicio</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Obras &#9660;
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="{% url 'url1' %}">Some text</a>
            <a href="{% url 'url2' %}">Some text</a>
            <a href="{% url 'url3' %}">Some text</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:20px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

I'll only include here the style for when the screen has changed, for simplicity:

```
/* navbar.css

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
    float: none;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

I got the Idea from the w3schools example and have done some major modifications